# Больше доменов или один, что лучше для SEO?

Tags: seo, домен, i18n, multilanguage

Есть такая ситуация:
имееться проект на 7 языках, для каждого языка купили отдельный домен, и проект уже успешно работает почти год
некоторые домены имеют больше посетителей из поисковых систем а некоторые меньше

когда мы запускались, и наш конкурент запускал почти точно такой-же проект, и тоже на 7 языках, только он поставил их всех на 1 домен

щас у него в 32 раза больше посетителей чем у нас
ПФ у него не лучше, дизайн не лучше, контент тоже не лучше

остаёться только вот данная фишка с доменом

- Вы как думаете, она может на столько повлиять на траффик?
- И стоит ли сделать переезд всех 7 доменов на 1 новый?

Comment: я думаю вам нужно начать с анализа  ваших поисковых запросов, семантики ваших сайтов, и сайта конкурента, перелинковать домены возможно,
не все так просто как кажется. может у вашего конкурента больше трафика но меньше конверсии

Answer (score 1):

Вы распылили силы на 7 доменов, он сконцентрировал на одном. С этой точки зрения - да, количество доменов может повлиять на трафик. 
Переезжать всеми доменами на один стоит только после анализа всех ваших доменов, конкурента и их сравнения. 
Возможных причин различия в трафике может быть масса, наобум их все преречислять все равно нет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Повлиять может. Чем больше людей ходят на сайт из поисковика, тем выше он в выдаче этого поисковика. Упрощенно говоря, в то время как ваши 7 сайтов получили по Х заходов с поисковиков, сайт конкурента получил 7х и поднялся в выдаче, получая тем самым еще больше заходов.